# Create procedure which shows customer orders: summary quantitty and amount orders in individual years. Customer ID on input to procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I have problem with my procedure, because I don't know how to count quantity of orders in individual years

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Orders @id VARCHAR(10) 
AS 
    SELECT unitprice * quantity Amount, 
           Count([order details].orderid), 
           Year(orderdate) 
    FROM   [order     details] 
           INNER JOIN orders 
                   ON [order details].orderid = orders.orderid 
    WHERE  customerid = @id 
    GROUP  BY unitprice * quantity, 
              Year(orderdate), 
              [order details].orderid
```

I have to group by years, but I don't know how to do that. Please help me someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT YEAR(o.OrderDate) as yyyy, 
       SUM(od.UNITPRICE*od.QUANTITY) as Amount,
       count(*) as num_orders
FROM [Order Details] od INNER JOIN
     Orders o
     on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
WHERE o.CustomerID = @id 
GROUP BY Year(OrderDate);
```

Notes:

- Give all columns in the `SELECT` an alias, so you know what they are supposed to be doing.
- Table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all column names, so you know what table they come from.
- The only expressions in the `GROUP BY` should be the *unaggregated* columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Of course, that yes. Now, I understand everything. Thank you a lot :)